# Update Json Value with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm working on enabling and disabling a value with PHP that's stored with a config.json file I have for my modules. The format of the config file is

```
{
  "details": {
    "name": "Doxramos Core Login",
    "root": "index.inc",
    "language": "en_US",
    "ident": "dxcl",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author" : "Doxramos Development",
    "date" : "5/31/2016",
    "module_url" : "allthingscode.net",
    "author_url" : "allthingscode.net",
    "core": true,
    "version_tested": 1.0
  },
  "options": {
    "location": "right_well",
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

For my PHP Function I have it run

```
function ToggleModule($status, $configFile) {
    $string = file_get_contents($configFile);
    $json_a = json_decode($string, true);
    $json_a['options']['enabled'] = $status;
}
```

So with this all the parameters are passed successfully; the `$json_a['options']['enabled']` value is controlled by the post variable, but I don't know how to get the file to save afterwards.

Comment: the reverse of `json_decode` is `json_encode` and the reverse of `file_get_contents` is `file_put_contents` so `file_put_contents($configFile,json_encode($json_a))` should work.

Comment: Unfortunately no go. I appreciate it though.

Comment: Did it throw errors?

Comment: No errors. Not really sure how to get a var dump off of this. Editing files within php is new to me. If you wanted me to update a database I've got it, but this is all new grounds.

Comment: Try `var_dump([ "before" => $string, "after" => json_encode($json_a) ])` to compare the before and after state. Put it as the last statement of your function.

Comment: Will do. Gonna run the kids to school then come back and try to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114142/discussion-between-morgan-green-and-apokryfos).

Comment: You were correct with your first answer. The issue came in when it updated. I had the check `if($json_a['details']['enabled']==true) { //Return Enabled }` and the updated format was not done as true, but rather "true", so I just changed my check to `if($json_a['details']['enabled']=="true") { //Return Enabled }` and it works for disabling and enabling now.

Comment: Yes, variables from `$_GET` or `$_POST` are always strings, you need to do [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to transform them to what they should be, or just compare as strings.

Comment: Could you join me in chat for a minute?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It should help you. This will create new.json file

```
$fp = fopen('new.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($json_a));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Good answer, but not the one I ended up utilizing. Thank you.